# Can't get PHP's openssl_encrypt to match output from aes_encrypt in C

Tags: php, c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm not a programmer by trade, so please bear with me...

I have an application I am using that unfortunately stores passwords in plaintext in MySQL, which is something I do not want.  As the program does makes use of the OpenSSL library, I have access to the aes functions.

Below I've cobbled together demo code that uses these functions to encrypt a test string and uses MD5 to hash it (since the encrypted text is binary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        AES_KEY aesKey_;
        unsigned char userKey_[16];
        unsigned char in_[16];
        unsigned char out_[16];

        strcpy(userKey_,"1234567890abcdef");
        strcpy(in_,"texttoencrypt");

        fprintf(stdout,"Original message: %s\n", in_);
        AES_set_encrypt_key(userKey_, 128, &aesKey_);
        AES_encrypt(in_, out_, &aesKey_);

        char *output = str2md5(out_, strlen(out_));
        fprintf(stdout,"MD5 of Encrypted message: %s\n", output);

        AES_set_decrypt_key(userKey_, 128, &aesKey_);
        AES_decrypt(out_, in_,&aesKey_);
        fprintf(stdout,"Recovered Original message: %s\n", in_);
        return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Original message: texttoencrypt
MD5 of Encrypted message: 3675b450ae0415e5a8521b9bb7ee01ba
Recovered Original message: texttoencrypt
```

Now in PHP I am using this code to generate the various AES-128 encrypted strings and similarly, MD5ing the result:

```
<?php

$methods = openssl_get_cipher_methods();

$plain = "texttoencrypt";
$password = "1234567890abcdef";

foreach ($methods as $method) {

        if (preg_match('/AES-128/', $method)) {
                $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plain, $method, $password);
                $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password);
                echo $method . ' : ' . md5($encrypted) . ' ; ' . $decrypted . "\r\n";
        }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
AES-128-CBC : 08d6f8e2ae21a7a506fabf91adcc3b63 ; texttoencrypt
AES-128-CFB : ce10ea28d7607bd6514e478e025e47c6 ; texttoencrypt
AES-128-CFB1 : 6adde484b8bee26f9b1ca7856634586d ; texttoencrypt
AES-128-CFB8 : aea100f1473c0a3d6380dd0f28585e19 ; texttoencrypt
AES-128-ECB : 08d6f8e2ae21a7a506fabf91adcc3b63 ; texttoencrypt
AES-128-OFB : ce10ea28d7607bd6514e478e025e47c6 ; texttoencrypt
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting a match to the 3675b450ae0415e5a8521b9bb7ee01ba generated by the C code.  I've tried just about every comment I've seen on the PHP manual pages and here on SE, but can't get a match.

I can't modify the C code, just the PHP... so any pointers on how to get PHP to match the C output is certainly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
 AES_encrypt(in_, out_, &aesKey_);

 char *output = str2md5(out_, strlen(out_));
```

Who is taking care of null terminating `out` so `strlen` works as expected? Certainly not `AES_encrypt`.

Moreover in `strcpy(userKey_,"1234567890abcdef");` you are copying `17` bytes of data (you have to count the null terminator) to an array `16` of `char`.

Comment: My apologies... I am just trying to more or less copy the code from the app.  It just uses the basic aes_encrypt/decrypt and key setting functions as reference in aes.h.

This is all new to me... and I think I'm getting in over my head!